# Android canvas drawText from right to left

Tags: android, canvas

I have an app that handels Arabic too, but my Arabic users have a problem that the drawText flip the word .. Arabic must be from right to left. How do I make the canvas drawText from right to left?

[image]

See in the picture the highlighted text is the right text its a textView and it's fine. But the canvas DrawText the one in a circle is wrong. It must be from right to left, how do I make the canvas drawText from right to left?

Comment: thanks for adding the image, cuz i didn't have permission to add one x.x

Comment: can you show your code onDraw() how your drawing..

Comment: i don't have onDraw() .. i use drawText:         c.drawText(txt, (float) (c.getWidth()/2.7), (float) (c.getHeight()/2 + paint.getTextSize()/1.5), paint);

Comment: txt is my string name .. which is being used by the textview and the canvas, in the textview ( the highligted ) its properly, but in the canvas (the circle ) it must be Right to Left

Comment: if you use canvas.drawTextOnPath() you can draw text for your required direction..

Comment: i need it to be right to left, how ?

Answer (score 1):

On the canvas just create two points on sides where you want to draw text, and then create path between them. use this method it will work fine

```
Path path = new Path();
Paint paint = new Paint();
path.moveTo(p2.x, p2.y);
path.lineTo(p1.x, p1.y);
canvas.drawTextOnPath(String.valueOf(txt), path, (float) (c.getWidth() / (2.3)),  (float) (c.getHeight()/2 + paint.getTextSize()/1.5), paint);
```

Comment: thanks, but how do I create a point so I insert it replace of p2 and p1 cuz I get an error from the p's

Comment: Don't worry about the Point object if you don't understand it. Both of the methods above use two floating point variables so just use those or constants.

e.g: 
path.moveTo(106,80);
path.lineTo(3,80);

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that Android emulator that contains the Arabic language, I had the same problem but when I tried the application on an actual mobile device,It solved.
There are no problems in your application in the language, make sure Android emulator supports the Arabic language

Answer (score 1):

you can get subString from your string and draw in your canvas:

```
            Paint textPaint = new Paint();
            textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            textPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
            textPaint.setTextSize(20);
            textPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            textPaint.setStrokeWidth(1);


            String subString = mString;
            float textWidth = textPaint.measureText(mString);

           int endOffset = Math.round(rectWidth * (mString.length() - 1) / textWidth);
            if (textWidth > rectWidth) {
                endOffset =endOffset - 2;
                subString = mString.substring(0, endOffset);
                subString = subString + "..";
            }else{
                for(int j=mString.length();j<endOffset+1;j++){
                    subString+=" ";
                }
            }


            canvas.drawText(subString, padding , (float) (startHeight + eachHeight / 3 + textPaint.getTextSize() / 1.5), textPaint);
```

in this way we have a same result even in RTL or LTR string .

Answer (score -1):

If your target device is api level greater than 11 you can use rotateY=180 attribute in TextView element. Also the parent view should set to rotateY = 180.