# drawScaledText() not working for right-to-left language

Tags: java, android, arabic, hebrew

I'm trying to used drawScaledText() on a right-to-left language (Hebrew) and it flips the letters, as shown in [this link](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipMB07FRiskk1UNnF9pfJMqGCUlwyiqV7Zw9BWPfqsgoBt74dsxnXyLGkwzfyctSXQ?key=amt2ZXEtZ2VGeFFlcDAwQ3k4R0FDaExuemwwOVln).

here's the exact code:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    TextPaint paint = getPaint();
    paint.setColor(getCurrentTextColor());
    paint.drawableState = getDrawableState();
    mViewWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
    String text = (String) getText();
    mLineY = 0;
    mLineY += getTextSize();
    Layout layout = getLayout();

    for (int i = 0; i < layout.getLineCount(); i++) {
        int lineStart = layout.getLineStart(i);
        int lineEnd = layout.getLineEnd(i);
        String line = text.substring(lineStart, lineEnd);
        float width = StaticLayout.getDesiredWidth(text, lineStart, lineEnd, getPaint());


        if (needScale(line) && i != layout.getLineCount()-1 ) {
        //THIS IS THE LINE FLIPS RTL TEXT
            drawScaledText(canvas, lineStart, line, width);
        } else {
        //IF I BYPASS THE ABOVE IF STATEMENT, THIS LINE DOESN'T FLIP TEXT
            canvas.drawText(line, 0, mLineY, paint);
        }

        mLineY += getLineHeight();
    }
}
```

This code justifies text and is from [this repo](https://github.com/ufo22940268/android-justifiedtextview/blob/master/justifytext-library/src/main/java/me/biubiubiu/justifytext/library/JustifyTextView.java).

Why is this / how can I get around this? I saw somewhere that it might be possible to use `drawTextOnPath()` in place of `drawScaledText()` by drawing along a line which starts at right and goes to left 
([Android canvas drawText from right to left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121591/android-canvas-drawtext-from-right-to-left))

Unfortunately, the answers for that question didn't really explain what they meant by this and I haven't been able to get this to work

TL;DR: I want to draw justified RTL text. `drawScaledText()` flips text for some reason. Is there another way to draw text within specified bounds?